# Turn buttons inactive and change opacity

Tags: ios, button, binding, swiftui

I am fairly new to Swift, so please bear with me.

[screenshot when nothing's tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqS6A.png)

[screenshot when one button is tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9GbE.png)

I am trying to turn the other buttons, which are not tapped, inactive and change the opacity to 0.5.

So far I have tried using the $bindings but that did not work the way I wanted it to.

Here is the Code for my SelectionButtons:

```
struct SelectionButton: View {

var buttonText = "Selection Button"

var buttonColor = Color.white
var buttonWidth: CGFloat = 150
var active = false


var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        if active {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45)
                .frame(width: buttonWidth, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(Color("neonGreen"))
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:9, x:0, y:0)
            
            
            Text(buttonText)
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .bold()

            
        }else{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45)
                .frame(width: buttonWidth, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(buttonColor)
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)), radius:9, x:0, y:0)
            
            
            Text(buttonText)
                .font(.system(size: 18))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is how I use them:

```
@State var gelbesBlatt = false

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        
        
        
        Button(action: {
            self.gelbesBlatt.toggle()
        }, label: {SelectionButton(buttonText: "gelb", buttonColor: .white, buttonWidth: 150, active: gelbesBlatt)
        })
    }
    
    
}
```

Thank you!

If you have an idea how I could add combinations, so that specific buttons which belong together (like "Ganzes Blatt > gelb" and "Ränder > braun") can be selected together, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    @State var gelbesBlatt = false
    @State var btnBraun = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.toggleButton(button: 0)
                }, label: {SelectionButton(buttonText: "gelb", buttonColor: .white, buttonWidth: 150, active: gelbesBlatt)
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.toggleButton(button: 1)
                }, label: {SelectionButton(buttonText: "braun", buttonColor: .white, buttonWidth: 150, active: btnBraun)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    func toggleButton(button: Int) {
        if(button == 0) {
        self.gelbesBlatt = true
        self.btnBraun = false
    } else {
        self.gelbesBlatt = false
        self.btnBraun = true
    }
        self.gelbesBlatt.toggle()
        self.btnBraun.toggle()
    }
```